# Config.ini Cannot be read, or found

Tags: python, file, config, ini

So my config.ini is in my downloads, and my python file is in my

```
D:/Python Code Stuff I did
```

And config.ini is placed in

```
C:\Users\karam\Downloads\Vector_1.3\Vector_1.3\settings.ini
```

And when I try this code

```
config = ConfigParser()
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
configPath = os.path.join(path, "settings.ini")
print(config.sections())
config.read('settings.ini')
```

and the error I receive is

```
C:\Users\karam>D:/y/python.exe "d:/Python Code stuff I did/print.py"
[]
```

it just prints the brackets, when it should print the sections such as
[image]

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: C:\Users\karam>D:/y/python.exe "d:/Python Code stuff I did/print.py"
[]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `config.sections()` before reading the file. You need to read the file first.

You are finding the file path and not using it. you should use `configPath` in `config.read()` method.

**Try this:**

```
config.read(configPath)
print(config.sections())
```

Comment: Still does the same thing, it only prints brackets